# How can I activate another object via python when a object is in Edit Mode?

Tags: python

[image]

In Blender, there are three selected situations.
an active object, an "activate" item and selected objects.

Now, I know how to set an active object or selected object in Python.
And I know that to activate an object is about "bpy.ops.outliner.item_activate(deselect_all=True)
", but the operator needs the context about Outliner.

I need to activate an item as the selected situation in 3D Viewport.
How can I do that in 3D Viewport via Python.

Comment: I would essentially disregard the `outliner.item_activate` method, that's really not how you want to select objects in basically any scenario. To set the object as the active object you use `bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = your_object` and to set the object as selected you use `bpy.data.objects['your_object'].select_set(True)`

Comment: I know those APIs, but I need to activate another object (but the active object) to test the bugs  I meet.

Comment: You'll need to look into [overriding context](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.html#:~:text=It%20is%20possible%20to%20override,context%20member%20names%20in%20bpy.)

Comment: Thank you very much！That helps me a lot!